# How to make transparent background in google charts for internet explorer?

Tags: php, javascript

How can I make transparent background in Google charts for Internet Explorer?

I have used

`'backgroundColor':'transparent'`   and `'backgroundColor' = {fill: <color>};`

It works in FF, Chrome, Safari, and Opera but did not work in Internet Explorer.

Is there any way to make it transparent in Internet Explorer?

Comment: i am not sure but try `backgroundColor: {stroke:null, fill:null, strokeSize: 0}` and other would be adding blank png  image as background

Comment: Thank you very much ..for the reply...i have added 'backgroundColor':'#colorcode' same as the website bgcolor it works in all browsers thank you verymuch

Comment: with pleasure...please do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by either

```
backgroundColor: {stroke:null, fill:null, strokeSize: 0} // or
 backgroundColor:#colorcode ;
```

or you can add blank png image background to do this

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem, Internet Explorer 7,8 will display Chart on iframe, so i added jQuery to transparent background of body tag on Iframe use event Ready of Chart.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});                                
                            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);                                
                            function drawChart() {
                                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                    ['', ''],
                                    ['', 2],
                                    ['', 8]
                                ]);

                                var options = {
                                    colors: ['#b28dc1', '#79449a'],
                                    legend: {position: 'none'},
                                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                    pieSliceText: 'value',
                                    pieHole: 0.55,
                                    pieSliceBorderColor: 'none'
                                };

                                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart1'));
                                google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', addIETransparentBg);                                        
                                chart.draw(data, options);                                                                  
                            }
                            function addIETransparentBg(e) {
                                $("iframe").contents().find("body").css({'background': 'none'});
                            }
```